string interning vs address in memory
I have this code:
var a = "ab";
var b = string.Concat("a", "b");


Console.WriteLine(string.IsInterned(a)!=null); //True
Console.WriteLine(string.IsInterned(b)!=null); //True

Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(a,b)); //False

So the string a is compile time and is by default interned. The second one I suspected should behave in the same way as would be "a"+"b" which would also be interned. This seems to be confirmed by string.IsInterned(string) methods which both return True. However the address in memory is different which is indicated by object.ReferenceEquals(object,object) returning False. If both strings are interned then shouldn't they be actually the same object in the string intern table so the same reference?

“… string.IsInterned(string) methods which both return True” Well, no, they return a non-null value. Read the documentation to see what that means.

Ok, I agree, the IsIntenred doesn't return bool but it still returns the same string if the reference to it is found in the intern pool and null if not. I just compare them against null so in practice it means that if they are not null then they are interned

Side note: it is perhaps a shame that the compiler doesn't interpret string.Concat("a", "b") as (literally) "a" + "b", since the latter is evaluated at the compiler as the literal "ab"

"so in practice it means that if they are not null then they are interned" - no, that's incorrect; it means that a string with the same contents is interned (and it provides that interned instance as the result); but it does not (necessarily) mean that the string you provided is itself an interned string instance

No, it doesn’t return the same string (from the ReferenceEquals standpoint that you care about). If it did, there would be no reason to return a string instead of a boolean.

Ok, I get it now, just've tried the same with new System.Text.StringBuilder().Append("ab").ToString() and the behavior is still the same, it checks for the content and not the reference itself. Thanks for explanation

Now try:
var c = string.IsInterned(b);
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a, c)); // spoiler: True
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(b, c)); // spoiler: False

It is telling you "yes, I do have an interned value that contains "ab"" - but that doesn't mean that the reference you passed in is itself interned - just that the contents "ab" exist in the interned list.
